# Word (adjective) for "undelayable"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

What is the best term that can convey the message that something is "*undelayable*":

"*I had to work on tasks that can no longer be delayed/postponed* "

Instead, I would like to say: "I had to work on **undelayable** tasks..."

*UPDATE:*

"undelayable" is not a word: according to multiple sources including [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=undelyable&s=t), [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undelyable), and American Heritage. Articles and papers on [the topic](https://evolllution.com/opinions/delaying-tasks-failing-to-measure-the-importance-of-the-work/) also never used it as an adjective.

Comment: "Undelayable" is listed as an derived adjective in the dictionary.com entry for "[delay](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/undelayable)"

Comment: Urgent is another possibility.

Comment: ur·gent
ˈərjənt/
adjective
adjective: urgent

    (of a state or situation) requiring immediate action or attention.
    "the situation is far more urgent than politicians are admitting"
    synonyms: acute, pressing, dire, desperate, critical, serious, grave, intense, crying, burning, compelling, extreme, exigent, high-priority, top-priority; life-and-death
    "the urgent need for more funding"
        (of action or an event) done or arranged in response to a pressing or critical situation.
        "she needs urgent treatment"

Comment: Just because it doesn't appear in a dictionary, doesn't mean it's not a word. There are many rules for adding prefixes and suffixes which allow many many derived words that dictionaries just don't have the inclination to list. __'Undelayable' is paraneologistically producible.__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'time-critical'. Merriam-Webster's #2 definition of critical: 
a : of, relating to, or being a turning point or specially important juncture ·a critical phase
 : such as   (1) : relating to or being the stage of a disease at which an abrupt change for better or worse may be expected; also : being or relating to an illness or condition involving danger of death ·critical care
 ·a patient listed in critical condition
    (2) : relating to or being a state in which or a measurement or point at which some quality, property, or phenomenon suffers a definite change ·critical temperature

b : indispensable, vital ·a critical waterfowl habitat
 ·a component critical to the operation of a machine

c : being in or approaching a state of crisis ·a critical shortage
 ·a critical situation

d : crucial, decisive ·a critical test
 (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical)

Comment: Thank you - "Time-critical" appears to be very close to what I was looking for, although I don't understand the reason for citing the entire definition of the word "critical" :P

Comment: This forums criteria for an answer is a minimum of 30 characters, thus I added the definition. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I actually used. If you find the question to be valuable, don't forget to vote it up!

Comment: You are most welcome. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. *undelyable* **is** a word.
2. There may be no single-word exact synonyms for that.

Try *undeferrable*, *pressing*, or *urgent*.

https://glosbe.com/en/en/undelayable
http://www.yourdictionary.com/undelayable
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undelayable

(emphasis added:)

> The definition of compatible mechanisms between the countries became **undelayable**, … ([Danièle Joly - 2004](https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=0754609472))
>
> …  which in the course of social and political development have shown themselves to have become unavoidable and **undelayable**. ([Hal Draper - 1977](https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=085345387X))
>
> The Governments of the U.S.S.R., … Hungary and the German Democratic Republic will do on their part everything in their power to facilitate the accomplishment of these **undelayable** tasks … ([United States. Dept. of State. Office of the Historian - 1985](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=49auH_svaskC))